# jQuery plugin fails when bundled in MVC

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I've got an MVC 4 application that makes use of jquery, jquery ui, jquery validation, and [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) datetimepicker plugin. These are added using the bundling tools in MVC.

It all works fine just running it with F5. However, when I deploy it to the server, there is a script error somewhere in the plugin (Object doesn't support this action). If I debug it locally and set   in the web.config, then it fails with the same error.

One difference is that when it's running in debug, it's not being bundled. Could that be causing a problem? What is going on that could cause this error?

Comment: Add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` in your `BundleConfig.cs`. Now it will bundle scripts in debug and it usually outputs then when and why error occured as a top comment in bundled `*.js` file.

Comment: @Qmal: I did that, and it just took me to the offending line in Visual Studio as oppsed to in my browser which it was doing before. I've perused the javascript a bit, but I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: @kettch I will import this plugin in my solution to test, brb.

Comment: @kettch I imported this (https://raw.github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js) script into my bundles and it's working fine, no errors and minifying is successful. I am missing something? This was the script? If so, error should be in your code than. Make sure to load it after jquery.

Comment: Yes, that's the script I was using. I'm loading the scripts in the following order: jQuery, jQueryvalidation, jQueryUI, datetimepicker

Comment: I should add that I also split it into it's own bundle to make sure that it definitely was being loaded after everything else. So far, the only difference between working and not working is the bundling.

Comment: For now it seems to work if I bundle everything else, and don't bundle this one script.

Comment: @kettch I have the same issue and the same workaround to not bundle this script. This issue was noted on the timepicker github issues a few months ago, but hasn't received any attention. https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/377

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon the same problem and then the problem solved by rename the `.min.js` file to `.js` (removing the `.min`)

Comment: Don't know what the deal was here, but his ended up being the case for me also. Worked in prod, didn't work in local.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and managed to isolate the code that causes the error to occur in the bundled output.

[I sent a pull request to the author with the fix](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/pull/540).

Answer (score 0):

The automatic minification when using bundles is causing the problem.

If I reference `JQuery` directly in my `_layout.cshtml` file:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")
```

The problem goes away.

Comment: JQuery isn't the issue here, it's the DateTimePicker plugin. As mentioned in the comments above, this is a known issue with this particular plugin. I'd rather have JQuery bundled and not have to worry about hard-coded version strings.

Answer (score 0):

A solution even thought it's an old question

To ensure that this doesn't happen, just make sure that all your js functions ends with ;

```
function someName(){

}; <- the important part!
```

Or you can remove all the comments in the .js file..